# Intent action for launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

the question is straight...

I want to develop a simple `launcher application`. then for which `Intent`action I have to listen to open All available `apps`(show as Grid as default launcher) when user press on `Applications`button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own listview. It takes me about 30 min.

first get all installed apps with `List<ApplicationInfo> apps=getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);`

then show tem on list or grid with your custom adapter

For example you can show app name and icon

```
holder.tv.setText(getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(apps.get(arg0)));
holder.imgv.setImageDrawable(getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(apps.get(arg0)));
```

and add onItemClick action to run application with

```
String PackageName=apps.get(arg0).packageName;
Intent intent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PackageName);
startActivity(this, intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the applications button by your self. Some thing that will start like this:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Because you are the one who will lunch the applications you should know when they start ;)